# JSoup how to select and get specific information

Tags: android, html, regex, jsoup

I'm trying to select and get into a variable an specific html info. But first I'm trying to show this information as best as I can. The problem is that the page where I want to extract info, doesn't have a clear class identificators or it's hard to me to see how can I extract that information.

This is my Jsoup code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tvmaximo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvmaximo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvmaximo);

        new BackGroundTask().execute();

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
               URL url= new URL("http://www.myweb.com");
               /*Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();*/
               Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();
               /*Elements elements = doc.select(".lyrics").first();*/

               //get page title
               /*String title = doc.title();*/

               Elements elements = doc.select("td.headerRouteText"); 


               String maximo=elements.html(); 

                return maximo; 


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            tvmaximo.setText(result);
            System.out.println(result);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }




    }


}
```

And here it is the html from where I want to save: "MÍNIMO", "MÁXIMO", "VALOR MEDIO" and 89,99 , 47,341 and 17,3. Each value in a different variable. 6 variables in total:

```
<tr>
   <td align="center">
      <table>
      <tr><td align="center" class="cabeceraRutaTexto" colspan="2">MÁXIMO </td>
      <td align="center" class="cabeceraRutaTexto" colspan="2">VALOR MEDIO </td>
      <td class="cabeceraRutaTexto" align="center">MÍNIMO </td>
 </tr>    
 <tr><td align="center" class="cabeceraRutaTexto">89,99 <img        
      SRC="../Diseno/imagenes/euro.gif" WIDTH="7" HEIGHT="8"> /MWh</td>
     <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="center" class="cabeceraRutaTexto">47,341 <img 
           SRC="../Diseno/imagenes/euro.gif" WIDTH="7" HEIGHT="8"> /MWh</td>
     <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
     <td align="center" class="cabeceraRutaTexto">17,3 <img           
          SRC="../Diseno/imagenes/euro.gif" WIDTH="7" HEIGHT="8"> /MWh</td>
 </tr>
    </table>   
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, it's difficult to create the regex line because the lack of references to
build it. How can I do this with Jsoup? Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Now, thanks to all of your explanations I fixed the problem as you can see:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView tvmaximo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvmaximo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvmaximo);

        new BackGroundTask().execute();

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(Void... params) {


            try {

               URL url= new URL("http://www.myweb.com");
               Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();

                       /get elements table 1 (graphic table) */
                       Elements elementsgraphic = doc.select("div.divns6");
                       elementsgraphic.size(); //2

                       /* get elements table 2 (normal table) */
               Elements elements = doc.select("td.cabeceraRutaTexto");
               elements.size(); // 6

                  String barra1= elementsgraphic.get(0).text();       

               /* text values from table 2 */
                  String titulotxt = elements.get(0).text(); // TÍTULO
              String maximotxt = elements.get(1).text(); // TEXTO VALOR MAXIMO
              String mediotxt = elements.get(2).text(); // TEXTO VALOR MEDIO
              String minimotxt = elements.get(3).text(); // TEXTO VALOR MINIMO

           /* numeric values from table 2 */

                  String maximo = elements.get(4).text(); // NUMERICO VALOR MAXIMO
                  String medio = elements.get(5).text(); // NUMERICO VALOR MEDIO
                  String minimo = elements.get(6).text(); // NUMERICO VALOR MINIMO

                   return maximo;





            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            tvmaximo.setText(result);

            /*System.out.println(result);*/
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }




    }


}
```

1. Now I've got two more questions, what can I do to take the "18" and "8" values from the "activadiv" in the next code? I'm trying with:

   Elements elementsgraphic = doc.select("div.divns6");
   Elements elementsgraphic = doc.select("div#divns6");
   Elements elementsgraphic = doc.select("changeImage('barra1");

etc... and the app crashes at every attempt. I know the error It's on regular expression.

On the other hand.. I've been trying to return all these variables to "OnPostExecute" using an array but the program bounds error because  Asynctask wouldn't let me return an array. Thank you again for your patience.

```
 <table>

   <tr><td><div name='divns6' id='divns6' style='position:relative;visibility:hidden;'       
        width='400' height='160'><table valign=botton cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' 
        border='0'><tr     valign='bottom'>
    <td width=15 valign="bottom" height=150><a href="javascript:void(null)" 
             onMouseOver="changeImage('barra1','','47',2);activadiv('barra0','18');" 
             onMouseOut="changeImage('barra1','','47',0);desactivadiv('barra1');"><img 
             NAME="barra1" width="11px" height="47" border="0"></a></td>

    <td width=15 valign="bottom" height=150><a href="javascript:void(null)" 
             onMouseOver="changeImage('barra2','','21',2);activadiv('barra1','8');" 
             onMouseOut="changeImage('barra2','','21',0);desactivadiv('barra2');"><img 
             NAME="barra2" width="11px" height="21" border="0"></a></td>

      </td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select them and extract by location, like:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("td.cabeceraRutaTexto");
elements.size(); // 6
elements.get(0).text(); // MÁXIMO
elements.get(1).text(); // VALOR MEDIO
...
// or just the one you want
doc.select("td:eq(0).cabeceraRutaTexto").get(0).text() // MÁXIMO
```

updated from comments: getting `18` from the given html has another level of complication as its a part of a javascript code, the following code will give the desired value, though bare in mind that there are better ways to parse and extract part of javascript.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml);
String onMouseOver = doc.select("a").attr("onMouseOver");
// while this will work, there are more robust ways to parse javascript
onMouseOver.split("'")[9];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and concise explanation. It worked like a charm!

Comment: Please, how can I get the "18" value from the next html code?:

<table>

   <tr><td><div name='divns6' id='divns6' style='position:relative;visibility:hidden;'       
        width='400' height='160'><table valign=botton cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' 
        border='0'><tr     valign='bottom'>
    <td width=15 valign="bottom" height=150><a href="javascript:void(null)" 
             onMouseOver="changeImage('barra1','','47',2);activadiv('barra0','18');" 
</td>

Hope yo can help me with this regex one more time.

Comment: Wow!! I am very, very grateful to you!! the code is now as follows:

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();
String onMouseOver = doc.select("a").attr("onMouseOver");
String barra1 = onMouseOver.split("'")[9];

But I know it's not the best way to do it, I'll take a look to improve everything when I finish the app. Anyway I've never been good with regex.

Thanks for all again.

Comment: I was thinking, ¿this code takes the first the OnMouseOver after the first a href appeared? Or what is it doing exactly?

If I want to take information the same way from another line, It's possible to do something like "take the second OnMouseOver after the second a href" and "take the third OnMouseOver after the third a href..."? Thank you again.

Comment: in html you can have multiple elements with the same name (for example `<a>`) but you cant have multiple attributes with the same name, this `<a href='...' href='...'>` is not a valid html, you can get the third `<a>` by doing something like `doc.select('a').get(2)` google for css selectors for more info

Answer (score 1):

```
Elements elem = doc.select("td.cabeceraRutaTexto");

for(Element el : elem)
{
Log.e("elements :" , el.text());
}

or 

for(int i = 0;i<elem.size();i++)
{
Element el = elem.first();
Log.e("element" + i + ":",el.text()); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'sorry I don't have the reputation to vote you up as you deserve.

Comment: you're welcome it doesn't matter if this is work for you it is fine for me